# Python: Iteration Practice looking to break out of two loops

Tags: python

I am having some issues with loops, In general my question is how to break out of two loops. Line 60 is what I am referencing to, When I complete the code with valid values and then select yes to add another persons values it asks for weight first instead of height.

UPDATE: I am a self taught programmer with a very basic mindset of programming at this moment, I apologize if this has a really simple solution. I am just trying my best to learn as I go.

```
CONVERSION_FACTOR = 703
YES="YES , yes"
NO="NO , no"

print("")
print("Hello, and Welcome to the BMI Calculator, please follow the instructions and input numeric values only!")

while True:

 try:
    height:float = float(input("Please enter the person's height in inches:  "))
    isvalid = True
 except:
    isvalid =False

 if not isvalid:
    print("that input is not vaild please enter the person's height as a numeric value only!.")
    continue
 else:
 
  if 20 <= height and height <= 120:

    while True:
      try:
        weight:float = float(input("Please enter the person's weight in pounds:  "))
        isvalid = True
      except:
          isvalid =False
     
      if not isvalid:
          print("that input is not vaild please enter the person's weight as a numeric value!")
          continue
      else:
       
        if 10 <= weight and weight <=400:
            Bmi = weight / (height ** 2) * CONVERSION_FACTOR
            stop_weight = weight * 0.85
            for i in range(0, 100):
                if  Bmi < 16:  
                 category = "severely underweight"
                elif 16 <= Bmi < 18.5:
                 category = "underweight"
                elif 18.5 <= Bmi < 25:
                 category = "healthy"
                elif 25 <= Bmi <= 30:  
                 category = "overweight"
                else:
                 category = "obese"

                if weight < stop_weight:
                  break
                print("The BMI for a", + float(round(height,1)), "inches tall person who weighs", + float(round(weight,1)), "lbs. is",
                          + float(round(Bmi, 1)))
                print("which is categorized as " + category)
                percent_weight = round(weight * 0.05,1)
                weight = weight - percent_weight
                
        else:
            print("Please enter a weight of at least 10 pounds and no more than 400 lbs")
            continue

# Ask if user wants to continue
        while True:
            resume = input(str("would you like to input data for another person? Please only input YES or NO "))
# both statements to allow the program to repeat from the beginning
            if resume == "YES":
                break
            if resume=="yes":
                break
# both statements to end the program when user doesn't want to continue
            if resume == "NO":
                print("thank you have a nice day!")
                exit()
            if resume=="no":
                print("thank you have a nice day!")
                exit()
# A check to see if the values entered make sense
            else:
                print("You have entered an invalid input please try again")
            continue
# chevck for height to make sure it is within the set range
  else:
    print("Please enter the height between 20 and 120 inches")
    continue
```

I have tried playing with the indent levels and trying different if statements with no avail. any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion would be to use a function and to just return

```py
for i in range(10):
  for j in range(10):
    if condition: return
``
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a solution. I attempted to set this function up in my code using weight as a condition and cannot get it to work correctly maybe I am missing something?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: it says return is an invalid syntax

Comment: for i in range(0, 100):
                for j in range (10):
                    if weight: return

Comment: that should work... try just returning 0 or something

Comment: You probably have something indented wrong or missing a colon

Comment: The above answer answered my questions thank you @walker for your help.